# Program for graphing special functions, such as $f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x\in\mathbb Q\\ 0,&\text{if }x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$

Tags: math-software

My question is based on the fact that if there is any special program, that allows to graph certain peculiar functions such as the following, $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb Q; \\ 
0,  & \text{ if } x\notin \mathbb Q. 
\end{cases}$$ Or, $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } x\in(\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q)\cup \{0\}, \\ 
1/q & \text{ if } x=p/q,\ \gcd(p,q)=1,\ p\neq 0. 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Graphing $f(x)$ is quite problematic, as computers (having finite decimal expansions) effectively consider every real number rational.

Comment: Graphing $f(x)$ is impossible, computer or no computer.  Given any real number $(r)$, rational or irrational, and any $\delta > 0$, no matter how small, there will be both a rational and an irrational number in the neighborhood around $(r)$, of radius $\delta.$

Comment: Graphing $g(x)$ is impossible as well. The reason is the same.

Comment: The image of that function will look like function const = 0 because rationals have 0 measure, whole measure is in irrational numbers.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much for clarifying my doubt about those two functions.

Comment: One has to wonder why $0$ gets to be an honorary irrational in the second function, rather than have $g(0) = 1$ like all the other integers.